# Overflowing on phone screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

There is extra white space in the right of the body which appears only on mobile screens despite that i'm making overflow-x :hidden to the html and the body tags and all the page is the same width

[image: Screenshot for the problem]
[html,body styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB31B.png)

//css file link

https://github.com/Jjemy/Landing-page/blob/main/src/App.scss

Comment: Try to add code in the post itself instead of providing reference image of code

Comment: Use inspect element to see what exactly is overflowing, then just add your `overflow:hidden` to its container

Comment: I've appended the css file,
And now i'm trying to figure out which element is overflowing but still nothing appears

Comment: Please go read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1427878) and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the max-width: 100vw, is affecting the width. Try taking it out as this may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I've made it but still the problem exists

Answer (score 0):

I've figured the cause out ..
I'm giving some images a position absolute and when i change it the problem disappears but this affect the images position,
is there any other option?